# How to match 2 rows column in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
index   Value   Next_value   number    date
0       ABC     DEF2          3        1/1/2023
1       ABC     DEF2          4        2/1/2023
2       BDC     DEF2          1        3/1/2023
3       BDC     CCC2          2        4/1/2023
4       CCC     ABC           10       5/1/2023
5       DEF     BDC           11       6/1/2023
6       ABC     DEF3          7        7/1/2023
7       BDD     ABC           8        8/1/2023
```

I am trying to shift the row by 1, if the Next value matches with the value in the previous row. Above example, index 4 (Next value == Value in index 1; index 0 not considered, because index 1 is latest with date) and index 5 Next value matches with Value in index 3 (index 2 is not considered because index 3 is latest with date) also 7 matches with 6 because 6 appears the latest record (date). You can assume the dataframe is sorted based on date and time

Since my dataframe is very huge, I am not preferring cross join. The output the I expect is

```
index   Value   Next_value   number  prev_number  date
0       ABC     DEF2          3      NaN          1/1/2023
1       ABC     DEF2          4      NaN          2/1/2023
2       BDC     DEF2          1      NaN          3/1/2023
3       BDC     CCC2          2      NaN          4/1/2023
4       CCC     ABC           10     4            5/1/2023
5       DEF     BDC           11     2            6/1/2023
6       ABC     DEF3          7      NaN          7/1/2023
7       BDD     ABC           8      7            8/1/2023
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(by='date')

df['prev_number'] = pd.merge_asof(
    df, df,
    left_by='Next_value', right_by='Value',
    left_on='date', right_on='date'
)['number_y']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   index Value Next_value  number       date  prev_number
0      0   ABC       DEF2       3 2023-01-01          NaN
1      1   ABC       DEF2       4 2023-01-02          NaN
2      2   BDC       DEF2       1 2023-01-03          NaN
3      3   BDC       CCC2       2 2023-01-04          NaN
4      4   CCC        ABC      10 2023-01-05          4.0
5      5   DEF        BDC      11 2023-01-06          2.0
6      6   ABC       DEF3       7 2023-01-07          NaN
7      7   BDD        ABC       8 2023-01-08          7.0
```

Comment: Added one more complexity to the question. Sorry forgot to add it

Comment: @python_interest the logic is still not fully clear, I assume you want the last occurrence per Value? Have a look at the update and let me know

Comment: almost there. But one issue is it always takes the latest value for each Value. In case the value and next value matches at the later half of the dataframe, it always takes the last value for the matched records - updated

Comment: @python_interest it's getting trickier, see update ;)

Comment: I also added a graph of the values/number, so we chose here the latest number per edge (pair of Value/Next_value) and then map the duplicated in order where they are found (ABD-DEF2 for the first map, ABC-DEF3 for the second), please let me know if the logic is correct

Comment: It's a deduplicating index: the rank of the duplicates

Comment: actually most of them are not matching... :/ - I will update the question once again

Comment: @python_interest you must give a clear explanation of the logic, you can't just change the input and hope that we'll magically find the correct approach ;)

Comment: I didn't change my question. I was giving date column for better clarity

Comment: @python_interest ok, fair enough, I think I got it, but this wasn't clear from the beginning. Check the update

Comment: Sorry for confusion @mozway

Comment: No worries, I hope this is finally what you want ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use cross-mapping (between columns):

```
df.assign(prev_number=df['Next_value'].map(dict(zip(df['Value'], df['number']))))
```

- `dict(zip(df['Value'], df['number'])))` - while constructing will capture/assign the last among duplicated `Value` keys

---

```
   index Value Next_value  number  prev_number
0      0   ABC       DEF2       3          NaN
1      1   ABC       DEF2       4          NaN
2      2   BDC       DEF2       1          NaN
3      3   BDC       CCC2       2          NaN
4      4   CCC        ABC      10          4.0
5      5   DEF        BDC      11          2.0
```

Comment: added a little complexity to the problem.Sorry forgot to add this upfront

Comment: almost there. But one issue is it always takes the latest value for each Value. In case the value and next value matches at the later half of the dataframe, it always takes the last value for the matched records - updated

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `drop_duplicates` and `map`:

```
mapper = df.drop_duplicates('Value', keep='last').set_index('Value')['number']
df['prev_number'] = df['Next_value'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   index Value Next_value  number  prev_number
0      0   ABC       DEF2       3          NaN
1      1   ABC       DEF2       4          NaN
2      2   BDC       DEF2       1          NaN
3      3   BDC       CCC2       2          NaN
4      4   CCC        ABC      10          4.0
5      5   DEF        BDC      11          2.0
```

Comment: almost there. But one issue is it always takes the latest value for each Value. In case the value and next value matches at the later half of the dataframe, it always takes the last value for the matched records - updated

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    if ss.name>0:
        ss1=df1.loc[:ss.name-1].query("Value==@ss.Next_value").tail(1)
        if ss1.size>0:
            ss["prev_number"]=ss1.number.squeeze()
    return ss

df1.apply(function1,axis=1)
```

out

```
 Next_value Value  index  number  prev_number
0       DEF2   ABC      0       3          NaN
1       DEF2   ABC      1       4          NaN
2       DEF2   BDC      2       1          NaN
3       CCC2   BDC      3       2          NaN
4        ABC   CCC      4      10          4.0
5        BDC   DEF      5      11          2.0
```